# Почему, возникает ошибка в создании экземпляра класса библиотеки geolite2?

Tags: python, geoip

Есть журнал accessLog, его нужно обработать. Одной из задач это дополнить данные о пользователе по айпи. Например определение страны.
Для этого я хочу использовать библиотеку python-geoip-geolite2.
Согласно документации создаю экземпляр класса, но появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\NIR\main2.py", line 5, in <module>
   match = geolite2.lookup('17.0.0.1')
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\geoip.py", line 364, in lookup
   return self._get_actual_db().lookup(ip_addr)
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\geoip.py", line 350, in _get_actual_db
   rv = self._load_database()
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\geoip.py", line 342, in _load_database
   return mod.loader(self, sys.modules[__name__])
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\_geoip_geolite2\__init__.py", line 9, in loader
   return mod.open_database(filename)
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\geoip.py", line 508, in open_database
   md = _read_mmdb_metadata(buf)
File "D:\NIR\venv\lib\site-packages\geoip.py", line 381, in _read_mmdb_metadata
   offset = buf.rfind(MMDB_METADATA_START,
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Вот мой код:

```
from geoip import geolite2

match = geolite2.lookup('17.0.0.1')
print(match.country)
```

Comment: ну  в ошибке же английским по белому написано, что в качестве аргумента api просит байты, а вы даете ему строку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940411/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str-in-geolite2-function-in-py - здесь есть ответ на ваш вопрос. вероятно, у вас не верная версия библиотеки.

Comment: @strawdog Да похоже библиотека старая просто и не совместимая с питоном 3. Я пробовал в колабе ставить что там советуют - ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @CrazyElf при установке библиотеки таким образом: pip install python-geoip-python3. Все заработало